# itext7 setbackgroundcolor after update 8.0.0

Tags: c#, field, itext7

How can I set the background of fields of an existing pdf file to white? In the version itext7 7.x.x there was the function .setbackgroundcolor. After updating to 8.0.0, the function does not exist. (The existing pdf file has colored fields. The flattern does not remove the colored background - a white or transparent background is desired.

.SetBackgroundColor is not a Member from  pdfformfield

Comment: The original pdf document has text fields with green fill color. In order to produce a better print version, the fill color should be white. With the version before 8.0.0 this worked with [field].setbackgroundcolor(ColorConstants.white). How does this work with the new version? The new version is necessary because checkfields are now displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [forms module changelog](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/releases/release-itext-core-8-0-0/breaking-changes-for-itext-core-8-0-0/forms-module-changes) for 8.0, this method was moved to PdfFormAnnotation.

Quoting the relevant part:

> PdfFormField class was split onto PdfFormField and PdfFormAnnotation. Methods related to widget annotations used from form fields were moved to PdfFormAnnotation:
>
> setPage, setBackgroundColor, setRotation, setAction, setVisibility, setBorderWidth, setBorderColor, setBorderStyle, setAppearance.

Compare the API docs for [7.2.5](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/7.2.5/classi_text_1_1_forms_1_1_fields_1_1_pdf_form_field.html#a33b3bb0350107728823fd8d5597f2a33) and [8.0](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_forms_1_1_fields_1_1_pdf_form_annotation.html#a1f8dd6e446c99f9d0f5286e5e6432ab8).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
iText.Kernel.Colors.Color colLightCoral = new DeviceRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral.R, System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral.G, System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral.B);
```

In  itext7 **7**.x.x you had to use this:

```
myField.SetBorderColor(colLightCoral);
```

In  itext7 **8**.x.x you have to use this:

```
myField.GetFirstFormAnnotation().SetBorderColor(colLightCoral);
```